# accesing Button from one class to another

Tags: android

I have declared a button in A.Class and have set disabled.

```
public static Button s1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sn1);
s1.setEnabled(false);
```

Now i want to enable this button in another class(B.class)
I tried enabling this button by giving 
 Button s2=A.s1;
But its throwing an error saying "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity"

Pls help me in correcting the error

```
    `First Class:

    public class Mapper extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
    {
public static int sng=0,c=0;
public static double lat;
public static double lon;
public String placenametemp;
public Bundle savedInstanceState;
public static int chk= MapMe.check;
 LocationManager locman1= MapMe.locman;
 MyOwnLocationOverlay mylocover=MapMe.myLocationOverlay;
public MediaPlayer msong=MapMe.mp;
***public Button s1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sn1);***



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 // Add Click listeners for all buttons
    View firstButton = findViewById(R.id.geocode_button);
    firstButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View secondButton = findViewById(R.id.latlong_button);
    secondButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View thirdButton = findViewById(R.id.presentLocation_button);
    thirdButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View selectsong=findViewById(R.id.song_select);
    selectsong.setOnClickListener(this);
    s1.setOnClickListener(this);
    s1.setEnabled(false);


    }
 }


Second Class :
    public class MapMe extends MapActivity implements LocationListener 
  {

Button s1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sn1);
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  // Suppress title bar to give more space
    setContentView(R.layout.mapme); 

    updateGPSprefs();

    // Set up location manager for determining present location of phone
    locman = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

    // Listener for GPS Status...   
    final GpsStatus.Listener onGpsStatusChange = new GpsStatus.Listener(){
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event){
            switch(event){
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    // Started...
                break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    // First Fix...
                    Toast.makeText(MapMe.this, "GPS has First fix",       
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    // Stopped...
                break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    // Satellite update
                break;
            }
            GpsStatus status = locman.getGpsStatus(null);


            Iterable<GpsSatellite> satlist = status.getSatellites();
        }
    };
   public  void fu(double a,double b,double c,double d)
{

    if((val==0)&&(val1==0))
            {
        mp.reset();
        try {

            check=1;
            System.out.println("matched");
            mp.setDataSource(link1);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            Toast.makeText(MapMe.this, "playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Song button1");
            ***s1.setEnabled(true);***
           System.out.println("Song button");
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

inside Class A :

```
public static Button s1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sn1);
s1.setEnabled(false);
```

Inside Class B:

you should Write : `A.s1.setEnabled(true);`

**EDITED**

inside Mapper.java  :

```
Class Mapper extends Activity{

public static Button s1;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                s1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sn1);
                s1.setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

inside Mapme.java  :

```
Class Mapme extends Activity{


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_new);


                Mapper.s1.setEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

try this out. Might Help you.

Comment: am still getting the error  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity"

Comment: can you put here what code you have Done inside your class A and Class B?

Comment: i have added the code Mapper.class i have declared Button s1 and i have set it to false. I wanna enable this in Mapme.class under the function fu();

Answer (score 0):

You are calling findViewById() in wrong location. You should call it from within some non-static method like onCreate(). This method i.e findViewById() is non-static, so you can not call it the way you have mentioned. So you should declare your variable as static and then set its value in onCreate() of the activity.

Why dont you just call findViewById() in B class and then disable the view. As long as the view is available in the currently loaded layout the following code in B class should do your job.

```
Button s1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sn1);
s1.setEnabled(false);
```